# vue init webpack fail to install in windows 7

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to install vue-cli in windows 7 machine. But it fails to create the application with webpack template option. Please help me to sort out the issue.

```
F:\vue>vue init webpack my-app

? Project name myapp
? Project description test vue app
? Author test
? Vue build (Use arrow keys)
> Runtime + Compiler: recommended for most users
 Runtime-only: about 6KB lighter min+gzip, but templates (or any Vue-
 specific HTML) are ONLY allowed in .vue files - render functions are 
 required elsewhere
```

Find the below node, npm, vue details

```
npm -v : 3.10.10
node -v : v6.11.0
vue -V : 2.8.2
```

Comment: You're only showing the first four steps of the configuration prompts. Did you go through all the prompts? Did it give you any sort of message afterwards?

Comment: @thanksd - Just it asking for the four details when i install, other details it didn't ask.

Comment: So, your example shows you at the decision point for the `Vue build` prompt. Your choices are `Runtime + Compiler` and `Runtime-only`. What happens when you press Enter to select `Runtime + Compiler`?

Comment: @thanksd - I didn't aware that i have to enter from here, because of the command windows in bottom position. Came to know that we have to enter. Anyway thanks for your inputs.